# Call JSON API from within PHP Cron Job

Tags: php, api, curl, cron

I have a large system with an API.
On the frontend, JavaScript uses AJAX to talk to the API.

I have a PHP file that runs every 5-min as a CRON job.
I want this PHP code to interact with the API.
All it has to submit is query-vars.
All that is sent back is a single number.

For Example:
https://examplesite.com/api/create?id=1&data=2
This replies with a simple number that is the SQL last-insert-id.

EXTRA:
The API also needs two Session variables (user-id and system-id)
Can I just start session and set them before calling the API I guess?
I need the PHP script, ran by the CRON system, to talk to this API.

I have tried using cURL but no luck yet:

```
        //Need to add a user-id to session, does this work?
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user-id'] = 1;

        //HOW TO CALL API FROM CRON?
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/api/create?id=1&gid=2');
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/api/create?id=1&gid=2');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'file://../framework/api/create.php?id=1&data=2');

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        
        $result = str_replace("\n", '', $result); // remove new lines
        $result = str_replace("\r", '', $result); // remove carriage returns
        
        //Expect Result to be a number only
        file_put_contents("curl.log", "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] $result\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

The file method doesn't seem to work...  maybe path issue with ../
The http method doesn't seem to work...  server loopback issue?

Any advice on how to best have my PHP CRON robot use my API will be much appreciated.
I have simply copied API code into the CRON, but then I am duplicating code, and not allowing the robot to test the real API.

Thanks.

Comment: Session variables use cookies. You need to use the curl options that save and send cookies.

Comment: `session_start()` only works on web pages, not CLI scripts.

Comment: Maybe I could just include the PHP API file and capture the ourput?  I still need to set $_SESSION['user-id'] for it though...  can I just set it without start_session()?

Comment: The URL in the code you posted works for me without any cookies. What is the output of  `curl_error($ch)` if you call it after `curl_exec()`?

Comment: FYI:  Even ignoring the session vars...  I'm not getting an error logged from the cURL call either, and it has a long timeout.

Comment: APIs don't usually require session variables.

Comment: You can't use a `file:` URL as an API. PHP scripts are only executed when they're called through a webserver. If you use `file:` you just fetch the source code.

Comment: I just learned that thanks.  Finally got it to work with file:///full-path, but just the source code.  Maybe php include and capture output is the best way around the loopback problem.

Comment: It's an internal API, not external.  I am up for improving it though.  It needs to know the logged-in user and the system logged in to.  If I don't use session vars and just pass it in as data, then anyone could modify the data and pretend to be a different user or access a different system...  so how should I handle the API?

Comment: What is the purpose of the CRON job?  A watchdog?  There my be multiple ways to do what you want.  You can use session variables but that complicates the script.  I would need to know more about the API. Does the CRON job make a request identical to one made by a user?  Are you using SESSION variables to track the user's subsequent requests?

Comment: @Barmar sessions work in any PHP script.  See my answer.

Comment: @Misunderstood I may have misunderstood, I thought he wanted to use session variables in the client script, not the API.

Comment: This is the curl_error (thanks for that tip):   <i>ERROR #8:</i> Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT<br>123  I guess I need to setopts for user agent, still working on it.  I still think just including the php and capturing output might be the best approach

Comment: @Barmar I'm not really sure the SESSION is the best way.  I asked some questions and I had to respond now.  I live in Tampa and need to get out of Dodge.  If I can find some gasoline.

Comment: The API is what the JS on the front-end calls to do DB stuff.  The CRON does stuff on its own like updating Status at midnight and such, but this part of the CRON is a Robot user, that should use the system just as a user does (not with puppeteer or anything, I just want to use the same API that the frontend JS uses).  That frontend JS API assumes a logged in user and uses SESSION to handle that.

Comment: @RyanMcCormick I do not see any code that would generate that error.

Comment: The code that generates that error is part of my custom framework.  Thanks to TheGentleman for teaching me about curl_error().  I believe I could get past that error by passing in a User-Agent with setopts, and it is probably framework code causing that error.  In any case, dealing with sessions and cookies is a huge pain, so I am moving forward with my simple PHP include method I posted below.

Comment: Reading the question, I wonder if this works when called without cron. If it doesn't work there either, everything related to cron is irrelevant and could be removed from your question. Also, "no luck" and "doesn't seem to work" are not really descriptions of problems one can work with. Further, an API, is that to you a web-based feature to use via HTTPS? Point is, it doesn't have to be web-based at all and I'm not sure how you use that term. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you still wanted to use a session.  Your first curl should be a request that to a script that will create the SESSION then respond.

I created this get_cookie.php this to test this concept:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['time'] = time();
echo 'Time=' . $_SESSION['time'];
?>
```

I called this script to get the PHPSESSID from the response cookie

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/get_cookie.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
$head = substr($response,0,$skip);
$data = substr($response,$skip);
$end = 0;
$start = strpos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$end);
$start += 12;
$end = strpos($head,';',$start );
$cookie = substr($head,$start ,$end-$start );
file_put_contents('cookie.txt',$cookie);
echo "\ncookie=$cookie";
echo "\n$data\n";
```

RESPONSE:

```
cookie=PHPSESSID=bc65c95468d08dd02cc5ab8ab87bbd39
Time=1664237484
```

The CRON job URL, session.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Time=' . $_SESSION['time'];
?>
```

This is the CRON job script.

```
$cookie = file_get_contents('cookie.txt');
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/session.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

RESPONSE:

```
Time=1664237484
```

The result `"Time" ($_SESSION['TIME'])` is always the same as the time from the get_cookie.php.

Comment: Thanks, I might try this.  All I need with session is to pass in an ID, so I'm really just trying to get the API's $_SESSION['user-id'] to return 0 (the user-id of the robot) instead of an error.  Actually, I also need $_SESSION['system-id'] to return 'TestSystem'.  Other than that I don't need a real session.

Comment: @RyanMcCormick My idea is that you use curl to login like an actual user.  And save the PHPSESSID for any subsequent requests and it should behave the same as if it's a real user.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the write up.  If I ever need a full session I will come back to this, it is much appreciated.  For now, I think my solution will be much simpler for just passing a couple of vars in wherever the frontend API expects them (for my framework it is always just two $_SESSION vars and a handful of $_REQUEST vars - for the many front-end API files.  Then they all return either JSON or just a simple number depending on the API function).  Anyway, thanks for your help and I do plan to use your post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but in the end my alternate approach will be easiest and work best.  Here is the answer for others in need...

To have an external PHP (run via CRON) test an internal PHP API (that the frontend JavaScript usually talks to via AJAX), this is the easiest solution, including passing query-variables and session-vars.

STEP 1:  Don't worry about start_session() or passing any query variables, just add what you need to the arrays ahead of time.

STEP 2:  Capture the output buffer and simply include the PHP API file:

```
        $_SESSION['user-id'] = ' works! ';
        $_REQUEST['var']     = ' too ';

        ob_start();
        include '/var/www/sitename.com/framework/api/create.php';
        $result = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();              

        file_put_contents("/var/www/sitename.com/cron/curl.log", "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] Result: $result\n\n", FILE_APPEND);

        /* OUTPUT in curl.log:
        [2022-09-26 22:30:01] Result:  works! / too 
        */

        /* create.php API
        $user = $_SESSION['user-id']??' did not work ';
        $req  = $_REQUEST['var'    ]??' novar ';
        echo $user.'/'.$req;
        */
```

(obviously the CRON has to be on the same server as the website/api, otherwise you will have to use cURL with Cookie/Session/QueryVar-Arrays)